# Binding Panorama Background to Image in Isolated Storage

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, xaml, panorama-control

The background image for my Panorama control is stored in "/Shared/ShellContent/Background.png".

In my XAML I set the reference to:

```
<controls:Panorama.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/Background.png" />
</controls:Panorama.Background>
```

but the binding doesn't seem to work.

I have verified the existence of the PNG file using the excellent [Isolated Storage Explorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/).

Is this scenario even possible possible via XAML?

Answer (score 0):

Is this even a binding, it's a reference to the isolated storage.

If your isolated storage is empty when this is bound then it won't update because there is no `onNotifyPropertychanged`

Comment: The idea is to be able to reference an image in isolated storage rather than an application resource which uses the same syntax. It would also help with a known Mango bug for dynamically loading panorama backgrounds.

Comment: use `{binding path=background, ElementName=theUserControlName}` and in your code behind write a property with inotifypropertychanged that you assign from the code.

Comment: I've done that, but there is a bug in Mango where the Panorama control is not resizing the image after is has been loaded via a binding. Hence I was hoping to at least load the initial image via file reference rather than via binding.

Comment: do you do `yourPano.Measure(new Size());` maybe you could put this in the notify event?